# How does /data/data/yourpackage/databases/ get created in android app?

Tags: android

I am new to Java and Android. For using my own sqlite database in an android app, I followed the code given in [here](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) . I checked through adb (command prompt) that **databases** folder for my package does not exist. how does  /data/data/yourpackage/**databases**/ get created? 
Inside my package (org.example.database), only two things exist-cache and lib. 
I just copied the code from the reigndesign site and copied my own db file to the assets folder. I created my db file using sqlite.
what am i missing?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you posted, they are packaging the SqliteDb made on the workstation in the assets folder of the APK.  They also have two methods, createDataBase() and openDataBase(), which handle pulling the DB out of assets and putting them in the /data/... location.  Make sure you are calling those methods in your code (most likely only in the first onCreate() for your app).